# Number of monotonus subvectors in one vector

Tags: c++, arrays

I need to find a number of monotonus subvectors or arrays in my vector, or arrays, it doesn't mater. For example , I have vector `1234421257843`, and here i have 4 monotonus subvectors...

```
1. 1 2 3 4 4 
2. 4 4 2 1 
3. 1 2 5 7 8
4. 8 4 3, and number is 4.
```

I tried something like this ,but doesn't work...

```
int num(std::vector<int> v){
    int p(1),q(1);

    for(int i(0);i<v.size()-1;i++){
        if (v[i] > v[i+1] ) continue;
        else if(v[i] < v[i+1]) continue;
        else p++;
    } return p;
}
```

Comment: The monotonous subvector will be ascending or descending. You simply have to count the changes and add 1. So you need a flag telling you what is the current monotonous subvector direction and detect a change from that.

Comment: something like bool var...i'll try, thanks..

Comment: You need a first loop that determines the direction of the first subvector. It can start with 444... so you need to search for a number different of the first. This will tell you if the initial direction is ascending or descending. Then you start your search and counting of direction changes.

Comment: In the sequence `1 2 3 3 3 4 5`, would `3 3 3` qualify as descending subvector?

Comment: wouldn't, in fact, i have a problem to solve and finding number of descending, or ascending subvector is one part of my solving...problem is that you input one vector, input endes with 0, then you have to find largest monotonus(ascnding or descending) subvector, for example...1234421678965.... here largest substirng is 16789...

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will help you to find number of monotonus subvectors in one vector:

```
int num(const std::vector<int>& v) {
    int p = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i + 1 < v.size(); ) {
        p += (v[i+1] >= v[i]);
        for (++i; (i + 1 < v.size()) && (v[i+1] >= v[i]); ++i) {
        }

        if (i + 1 == v.size())
            return p;
        p += (v[i+1] <= v[i]);
        for (++i; (i + 1 < v.size()) && (v[i+1] <= v[i]); ++i) {
        }
    }
    return p;
}
```

But if you want to find largest monotonus subvector you don't need this. The task can be solved with the help of DP (Dynamic programming): you need two additional vectors a(n) and d(n), where a(i) / d(i) - is the length of longest ascending / descending subvector ending at position i: starting with a[0] = 1 you can easily calculate a[i + 1] = a[i] + 1 if v[i+1] > v[i] or 1 otherwise